# How to reproject a latlong J2000 coordinate image into latlong Galactic Coordinate image

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I have a 2x1 ratio lat/long projection of the night sky in J2000 equatorial coordinates (the fixed equatorial coordinate system on Jan 1.5, 2000).

I need to convert this into a 2x1 ratio lat/long image based on the galactic coordinate system (with the center of the image centered on the center of the milky way).

I know that the North Pole of the J2000 coordinate system is at 122.93200023 long, 27.12843056 lat, and 12.860114 East of North.

It's just a rotation and translation of the coordinates, so I would assume GDAL could handle that, but I can't find a function that seems to work.